# How to tween view.center in paper.js

Tags: javascript, paperjs, tween.js

So I'm trying to give the feel of smooth movement when reassigning the `paper.view.center` coordinates. The `center` object doesn't have a `tweenTo()` method. This is what I've tried using Tween.js:

```
let smooth = new TWEEN.Tween(paper.view.center).to({
    x: 650,
    y: 270
}, 900).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.Out).start();
```

Since it's a `Point` object reassigning the `x` and `y` values don't actually change the coordinates, because the proper way of reassiging it is to use another `Point` object (`new paper.Point()`). How could I tween the continuously new creation of a `Point` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a simple way of achieving what you want is animating the active layer position.
Here's a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.15/S/RZBNS8QwEIb/ypBLWyihHkSIeNqTIKjozfUQ03E3bpwpyXTrUvrfTbasDgzz9QzzMrMi+43KqJcDiturVjnuS+2YkoDz0QWEOyCc4MnKXm/OnXrexi1BNockGA0cPU56LdrLLNrej8nAdffX+vQhbDhw3qg4WtphVUZLc1vCek67wIR1oyUDKVjB+qrrmgIUHyJ/oRNtnfgjPtgTRi0TIr1yfTkzw8DJi2cyOf85S4BTCbDA0v5j/Rjtit10GUGbPO2ytpzgPT2O8jzavoKlbKwa84s+ItrDwJ4kKfP2vvwC) demonstrating a possible implementation.

```js
const circle = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'orange'
});
circle.clone().translate(100)

project.activeLayer.tweenTo(
    { position: { x: 50, y: 50 } },
    { duration: 700, easing: 'easeInOutQuad' }
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Did not think of using the activeLayer as a tweenable object.